# SetTextview in specific listview row with value obtained in dialogBox_Textview

Tags: android, sql-server, listview, textview, android-dialog

When I click my list a dialogbox opens, After i enter value in the textview in the dialog box using plus/add buttons, it needs to set the textview in the specific listview row with the value got from dialog box. The list view also has another textview which gets value from MSSQL database.

HOW MY LISTVIEW LOOKS

textviewValFromDatabase     textviewToSetFromDialogBox

---

textviewValFromDatabase     textviewToSetFromDialogBox

It doesnt know which position(ROW) to sit on and gets error

HOW I SET DATABASE ------------------------

```
  class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog loading;

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> obj;
    String[] customlistarray;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String s;
        ResultSet rs2;
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                String z = "Error in connection with server";
            } else {
                String et = "select Definition+'-'+cast( Rate as nvarchar(50)) as Item,categoryuserid,Rate from tblcategoryuser";
                Statement statement1 = con.createStatement();
                rs2 = statement1.executeQuery(et);
                int i = 0;
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs2.getString("Item"));
                    data.add(datanum);
                }

                String[] from = {"A"};
                int[] views = {R.id.itemname};
                AD = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.orderlist, from, views);

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        loading.dismiss();
        list.setAdapter(AD);
        kotno.setText(kot);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

MY LISTENER FOR LISTVIEW -----------------------------------------------

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position,long id)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogquantity);
            dialog.setTitle("Choose Quantity");

            qty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty);
            qtyd = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.qtyd);
            add = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            sub = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            okd = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okd);
            canceld = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.canceld);

            int aa=0;

            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int aa = Integer.parseInt(qtyd.getText().toString().trim());
                    aa += 1;
                    aaa = String.valueOf(aa);
                    qtyd.setText(aaa);
                }
            });

            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int aa = Integer.parseInt(qtyd.getText().toString().trim());
                    if (aa == 0.0) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "-No item Selceted-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        aa = aa - 1;
                    }

                    aaa = String.valueOf(aa);
                    qtyd.setText(aaa);
                }
            });

            okd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String aaaa = qtyd.getText().toString().trim();
```

// HOW TO SET TEXTVIEW HERE---------------------------------------------------

```
                    qty.setText(aaaa);
```

// I THINK THAT IS WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM------------------------------------

```
            dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            canceld.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you get a text from dailog now where you want to put it in list view as a header or in specific row.

Comment: Each row opens the dialog box and we can set value there and those values should sit in the textview in the row clicked.... ie i want to put them in the specific row (clicked row)